# I am not sure if my emails are encrypted or not

Tags: email, security, smtp, tls1.2, nodemailer

I would like to have certainty that my emails content is encrypted when are sent by internet.
I have simple service in node.js where I am using nodemailer. 
I've tried many different configurations for transporter. For now it is:

```
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'hostName',
    port: 465,
    secure: false,
    tls: {
      ciphers: 'SSLv3'
    }
  })
```

When I try to force using STARTTLS with this configuration, for ports: `25, 465, 597`:

```
requireTLS: true,
secure: false,
```

I have this error: `Error upgrading connection with STARTTLS: 500 5.3.3 Unrecognized command`
So it is clear that my server does not support STARTTLS.

When I try to force using TLS with:

```
requireTLS: true,
```

I have error: `4605283776:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:` so probably it means that I am 
trying to open a TLS connection against cleartext port (as said here: https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/993

So I can assume that my email are not secure and they are sent as plaintext. But ... when I am trying to check it by viewing headers of raw messages, I can see that TLS is used, (some data was changed for security)

```
   by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id s233id293944.29.2020.04.20.09.26.18
   for <example@g.domain.org>
   (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA bits=128/128);
   Mon, 20 Apr 2020 09:26:18 -0700 (PDT)
```

So why TLS is here? I think that I do not understand it and I am not sure if my emails are encrypted or not. I'll be grateful for any clafirications.

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: @ShekharSahu Then no. But now I think that making tests with some sniffer like wireshark would allow to capture traffic and then I could see if mail content is encrypted or not.